# Winning probability for throwing one and two balls

Tags: probability

Players $A$ throws one ball and player $B$ throws two. They are equally skilled and whichever ball gets closest to the hole wins. What is the probability that player $A$ wins?

My idea is to consider that player $A$ throws ball $1$ and player $B$ throws $2$ and $3$. We can describe which ball is the furthest and closest, and in the middle from the hole by a permutation of $1,2,3$. Since they are equally skilled, all six permutations should be equally likely, and of these six possibilities, in two cases player $A$ wins, which gives us probability of $A$ winning $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: That works for me, reading the question as saying the three throws are iid

Comment: Close your eyes when they throw the ball. Then guess if $A$'s ball is the one closest to the hole or any of the two other balls. $\frac{1}{3}$